# ASP.NET Core use Windows authentication when available and user name password when it isn't

Tags: asp.net-core, basic-authentication, windows-authentication

We have a web site we are developing using ASP.NET Core 5.0 that we want to allow both staff and clients access.

The staff are on the domain with Active Directory accounts and the clients are not.

We want to allow staff to be automatically logged in using Windows Active Directory authentication, but have the clients directed to a login page to verify their user name password against our database.

We have both of these things working, ie if we turn on just Windows authentication for the site staff can automatically be logged in. If we turn on just anonymous authentication, we have a log in page where all users can login with a user name and password.

The issue is if we turn both Windows authentication and anonymous authentication on we can use custom middleware code which calls

```
context.ChallengeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

to try to do a login with Active Directory, this works well and signs staff in using Active Directory silently, but for clients (ie public users) this will show the browsers login prompt asking for a domain user name password

[image]

We don't want this to appear for clients at all but rather to redirect them to our login page.

How can we make the call to ChallengeAsync do an Active Directory login if it can, but if it can't don't show the login prompt but rather just redirect to the login page?

Comment: this is complex problem. You can not enabled both auth. Just one win or anonymous and then you need setup microsoft internet options and add endpoint to trusted zone. Solve this problem is just a few hours of googling whats going on. Its easy but setup is fck...

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://damienbod.com/2018/04/15/supporting-both-local-and-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-identityserver4/) shows how to setup an ASP.NET Core MVC application to support both users who can login in with a local login account, solution specific, or use a windows authentication login. The identity created from the windows authentication could then be allowed to do different tasks, for example, administration, or a user from the local authentication could be used for guest accounts, etc. To do this, IdentityServer4 is used to handle the authentication. The ASP.NET Core MVC application uses the OpenID Connect Hybrid Flow.

Find the [repo code here](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreWindowsAuth).

Note: the IISExpress certificates need to be allowed when running.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44364/",
      "sslPort": 44364
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a comprehensive answer @Majid. unfortunately this is very similar to how our full code works. we downloaded the code to have a look and if you host it and browse to the site from an outside computer, and then press the "External account - windows" button it also shows the windows security login. so my question still stands is there is a way to stop that login screen showing, and authenticate users when it can and just throw a 401, etc when it can't authenticate them. we really don't want public users seeing our domain login allowing hackers a point to try to hack

Answer (score 0):

I found a backdoor solution and it kind of works.
First of all, we add 1 AD account for clients, and clients must enter username and password. If they authenticate successfully I send them to login page.